# JavaScript output not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello i want to display my program like this 
![enter image description here][1]

this is my css code im using this to get the layout for my javascript

```
        /*
            styles.css
        */

        body{
            background-color:#cecece;
            color:#fff;
            font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Sans-Serif;
            font-size:1em;
        }
        h1{
            color:#FF8000;
            text-align:center;
        }
        table{
            width:95%;
        }
        caption{
            font-size:1.2em;
            margin:10px;
            color:#FF8000;
        }
        th{
            width:33.333%;
            font-size:1.1em;
            text-align:left;
            color:steelblue;
        }
        #output{
            position:absolute;
            width:50%;
            height:70%;
            top:15%;
            left:25%;
            margin:0px;
            padding:10px;
            font-size:.9em;
            background-color:#2E2E2E;
            color:ivory;
        }
```

and this is my JavaScript Code where i am printing the output

```
                        var mytable = "<table><caption>Grading Results</caption>";
            document.write(mytable);
            document.write('<td><tr><th>' + "Student"+'</th><th>' +  "Mark!" + '</th><th>'+"Grade" + '</th> </tr></td>');
            for(var i = 0; i < markArr.length; i++){
            document.write(' <tr><td>'+studentArr[i] + space1+markArr[i] + space1+gradeAwarded[i] + '</td> </th> ');
            }
            document.write(' </tr>');
            document.write('<td>'+ "The Highest mark was : "+max+ ''+'</td> </th>');
            document.write('<td>' + "The Lowest mark was : "+min+''+'</td> </th>');
            document.write('<td>'+ "The Average mark was : "+average+''+'</td> </th>');
            document.write('<td>' + "number A grades : "+A+''+'</td> </th>');
            document.write('<td>'+ "number B grades : "+B+''+'</td> </th>');
            document.write('<td>'+ "number C grades : "+C+''+'</td> </th>');
            document.write('<td>'+ "number F grades : "+F+''+'</td> </th>');
            document.write('</table>');
```

Comment: @Robert, Seriously? Talk about using a steam hammer to push a nail in. That also has zero relevance to the question being asked.

Comment: You need to take a look at your table markup. You have a `table` tag, within which you directly make use of the `th` tag without defining a `tr` tag. Then you directly write the contents of the table without making use of `tr` and `td` tags. Your table markup is not looking good at all...

Comment: The table that you are constructing is totally wrong. You aren't adding any rows or cells. You are just dumping the output between. `<table>` tags

Comment: This question is unanswerable in it's current form. I can't tell from the picture what you want and you haven't posted your HTML.

Comment: @Liam: That was a COMMENT, not an answer. Surely, KO would be a little over the top here, but maybe he's just showing a simplified part of his project.

Comment: You create a table but don't put your data inside.You need to create some `tr` and `td` in order to insert them correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to change the following:

- Don't put a `<br/>` right after your closing `</th>`
- Put a `<tr>` before your first `<th>` and a `</tr>` after your last `</th>`
- Put a `<tr>` inside the for statement and a `</tr>` before its closing }
- Put every value between `<td>` and `</td>`
- Move `</table>` to just after the closing } of the for statement

EDIT:

This is what your javascript should look like:

```
var mytable = "<table><caption>Grading Results</caption>";
document.write(mytable);
document.write('<tr><th>' + "Student"+'</th><th>' +  "Mark!" + '</th><th>'+"Grade" + '</th></tr>');
for (var i = 0; i < markArr.length; i++){
    document.write('<tr>');
    document.write('<td>' + studentArr[i] + '</td>');
    document.write('<td>' + markArr[i] + '</td>');
    document.write('<td>' + gradeAwarded[i] + '</td>');
    document.write('</tr>');
}
document.write('</table>');
document.write(''+ "The Highest mark was : "+max+ ''+'<br>');
document.write('' + "The Lowest mark was : "+min+''+'<br>');
document.write(''+ "The Average mark was : "+average+''+'<br>');
document.write('' + "number A grades : "+A+''+'<br>');
document.write(''+ "number B grades : "+B+''+'<br>');
document.write(''+ "number C grades : "+C+''+'<br>');
document.write(''+ "number F grades : "+F+''+'<br>');
```

(Note: I didn't test this)

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(var i = 0; i < markArr.length; i++){
            document.write('<tr><td>'+studentArr[i] +'</td><td>'+ markArr[i] + '</td><td>'+gradeAwarded[i] + '</td></tr>');
            }    
 document.write('</table>');
     document.write('<ul>'+ '<li>The Highest mark was : '+max+ '</li>');
                document.write('<li>The Lowest mark was : '+min+'</li>');
                document.write('<li>The Average mark was : '+average+'</li>');
                document.write('<li>number A grades : '+A+'</li>');
                document.write('<li>number B grades : '+B+'</li>');
                document.write('<li>number C grades : '+C+'</li>');
                document.write('<li>number F grades : '+F+'</li>');
             document.write('</ul>');
```

In HTML structure you need to use properly table.
So you need to insert new table row (`<tr>`) and new cell (`<td>`), not just break lines (`<br>`).

More, you are looking for an unordered list `<ul>` and put this OUT of the table. Basic css for  has black dot for each list item `<li>`

You need then to style your table. In theory it's all correct if you'll fix your html. However maybe you'll have to add a margin-left to your new `<ul>`, let me say

```
ul {
  margin-left:2em;
}
```

If identation it's not enough, increase the value of "2" to "3" or "4". em it's basic measure based on current font size.

Comment: Explain the changes you made and why you made it.

Comment: let me the time to do -.-

Comment: How does this help change the font size, etc?, you also haven't explained it.

Comment: Ok - You prematurely hit the Submit Answer button - hoping you will fix it. Removed my downvote.

Comment: @Liam css appears ok, problem it's the DOM structure. In theory it will fix itself with a correct dom.

Comment: @callmekatootie was volountary to not lose the answer. I do that (as many others) when there are too many things to say about.

Comment: I edited the picture do u think u got any tips what i should do to get it any more like the other picture with the bullet points and name at the bottom

Comment: in my example i already suggested to you how to. If you like feel free to upvote :P @HelloWorld

Comment: I cleaned again my code however ul and li it's the right way